# Development of the Taylor series of $f(z)= \frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}$ around the point $z_0 = o$

Tags: complex-analysis

Can I just write $\frac{1}{1+e^{-z}}$ = $\frac{e^z}{e^z + 1}$ and because $e^z$ = $1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + ... = \sum_{n=0}^{∞}\frac{z^n}{n!}$ is $\frac{e^z}{e^z + 1}$ = $\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{∞}\frac{z^n}{n!}}{\sum_{n=0}^{∞}\frac{z^n}{n!} +1}$?

Thank you!

Comment: No, you *can't* just write what you wrote in the first line as that is **not** an equality.

Comment: I have $e^{-z}$ in first fraction

Comment: Ok, *now* you have it after you edited your question, and thus yes: that is an equality

Comment: Thank you very very much! :D